# Airflow with AD auth stuck in a redirect loop at login

Tags: python, active-directory, airflow

I have Apache Airflow using Active Directory for authentication.  The bind account has no problems connecting.  When I login Airflow just keeps redirecting from the login page, to /home and back to the login page over and over.  I turned on debug but this is all I get from the logs

```
"GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 -
"GET /home HTTP/1.1" 302 -
"GET /login/?next=http%3A%2F%2F10.18.0.20%3A8080%2Fhome HTTP/1.1" 302
```

No other authentication errors show up.

Authentication config

```
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI=conf.get('core','sql_alchemy_conn')
# Flask-WTF flag for CSRF
WTF_CSRF_ENABLED = True

AUTH_TYPE=AUTH_LDAP
AUTH_LDAP_SERVER='ldap://10.18.1.7:389'
AUTH_LDAP_USER_TLS=False
AUTH_LDAP_UID_FIELD='sAMAccountName'
AUTH_LDAP_SEARCH='ou=users,dc=test,dc=local'
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_USER='cn=svc_airflow,cn=Managed Service Accounts,dc=test,dc=local'
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD='passwordsomething'
# Uncomment to setup Full admin role name
AUTH_ROLE_ADMIN = 'Admin'
AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION=True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After finally getting some time to dig through this problem here is how I resolved it.

First, I overlooked the fact that there is a log level flag for the Flask App Builder piece of Airflow in the airflow.cfg.  I set that to DEBUG which gave me better output for troubleshooting.

I updated all my airflow related packages in my venv.

Once I did this I reinitialized the metadata database for Airflow.  I think this part was key.  I was seeing in the logs that I was binding successfully and logging in, however I think there was a group to role mapping issue causing the continuous 302 Redirect issue.

I narrowed down my webserver_config.py to the following:

```
import os

#from flask_appbuilder.security.manager import AUTH_DB

from flask_appbuilder.security.manager import AUTH_LDAP
from airflow import configuration as conf

basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
WTF_CSRF_ENABLED = True

AUTH_TYPE=AUTH_LDAP
AUTH_LDAP_SERVER='ldap://ldapserver:389'
AUTH_LDAP_USER_TLS=False
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_USER='cn=svc_airflow,cn=Managed Service Accounts,dc=testdomain,dc=local'
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD='supersecretpw!'
AUTH_LDAP_UID_FIELD='sAMAccountName'
AUTH_LDAP_SEARCH='ou=TestUsers,dc=testdomain,dc=local'
AUTH_ROLES_MAPPING={
        'cn=Access_Airflow,ou=Groups,dc=testdomain,dc=local':["Admin"],
        'ou=TestUsers,dc=test,dc=local':["User"]
        }
AUTH_ROLE_ADMIN = 'Admin'
AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION=True
AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION_ROLE = 'Admin'
AUTH_ROLES_SYNC_AT_LOGIN=True
AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_FIELD="memberOf"
```

Hope this possibly helps someone else!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to also set `AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION_ROLE` to point to the role that should be assigned for self-registerd users and this role has to exist and should have access to the UI.

Last time I had similar error was that the role was set to `Public` and public access was disabled - which caused the inifite loop. Not sure if that is your case but it helped me when I had similar issue.